# Event: Before Outlook close

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, add-in

I want to know, if it is possible to **cancel** the close event of Outlook. 
I use this event:

```
  ((Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_Event)Application).Quit += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_QuitEventHandler(ThisAddIn_Quit);
```

But this is too late.Outlook is already closed here. I want to ask the user if he is really sure to close Outlook. Are there any possibilities to cancel the Outlook Close event ? 
Thx.

Comment: As you accepted the possible fact, that there is no way, check out this one: www.msoutlook.info/question/52

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no `BeforeClose` like event in Outlook interop.